# How to fetching current month and year data from firebase in kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

Does anyone have any idea on fetching current month and year data from firebase database. I will be appreciated if someone tell me

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also indicate which month and year would you like to get.

Answer (score 0):

@kianhun4167 chai your question is not clear.

You cannot fetch dates from the firebase database until some date or month is already present inside the firebase database, its similar to when you create a new folder there's nothing inside it, you need to have some files inside that folder to access those.

Rather if you just want to get the current date or month or year or all. There are two different methods by which you can do that directly in android kotlin.

The first one would be

```
        val time :Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val format :SimpleDateFormat= SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault())
        val date :String= format.format(time)
```

The second one would be, both of them will generate the kind of same results

```
        val a:LocalDate = LocalDate.now()
        val date:String = a.toString()
```

You need to figure out which one works best for you.